# Only the latest version is available in Google Play Closed Test

Tags: testing, google-play-console

I used to access different versions submitted to Google Play's closed test track using their sharable URLs:
[https://play.google.com/apps/test/{package_name}/{version_code}](https://play.google.com/apps/test/%7Bpackage_name%7D/%7Bversion_code%7D)

Now it's not working and I'm only seeing the latest version which is available to testers on Google Play. What's going on?

Comment: Could be a bug, reach out to the developer support.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For developers reaching here with the same issue, we ended up using Internal Testing!